# Checkbox Value into array

Tags: php, jquery

I have jobsheet page for hours which is added to a array to put into a database. I now have the checkbox passing through to display the checkbox but I need to set the checkbox to the database for reading the next time. (Thanks to another forum user)

I have tried to use the Value ="1" but is passes the value even if it is checked or not.

So if the "add_overtime_hours" it is checked it needs a 1 into the field and not checked = 0

```js
<!-- this next section is to dynamically add the parts fields to the jobsheet page so more parts can be added on the page without it starting out too    large. -->    
<!-- this ext section is the Adding Hours on the jobsheet -->
var rownumhours = 0;

function addhours(obj, e) {
    rownumhours++;
    var hoursrow = '<p id="rownumhours' + rownumhours + '">Start Time: <input type="time" name="add_start[' + rownumhours + ']" size="4" value="' +
        $(obj).closest('span.headings').find('[name="add_start"]').val() + '">  Finish Time: <input type="time" name="add_finish[' + rownumhours + ']" value="' +
        $(obj).closest('span.headings').find('[name="add_finish"]').val() + '"> Date: <input type="date" name="add_date[' + rownumhours + ']" value="' +
        $(obj).closest('span.headings').find('[name="add_date"]').val() + '"> Overtime: <input type="checkbox" name="add_overtime_hours[' + rownumhours + ']" size="1" value="' +
        $(obj).closest('span.headings').find('[name="add_overtime_hours"]').val() + '"' +
    (($(obj).closest('span.headings').find('[name="add_overtime_hours"]').is(':checked')) ? 'checked' : '1') + ' "> Show Ovt: <input type="text" name="show_overtime_hours[' + rownumhours + ']" value="' +
        $(obj).closest('span.headings').find('[name="add_overtime_hours"]').val() + '"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(' + rownumhours + ');"></p>';
    jQuery('#hoursrow').append(hoursrow);
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
   jQuery('#rownumhours' + rnum).remove();
}
```

```html
<td colspan="3" align="left"><div id="hoursrow">
    <p> 
        <span class="text">
            Hours Labour :    
        </span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p> 
        <span class="headings">
            <span class="text">
                <span class="hours">
                    Start Time: <input type="time" name="add_start" size="4" />
                    Finish Time: <input type="time" name="add_finish" size="4" />
                    Date: <input type="date" name="add_date" size="4" />
                    OVT: <input type="checkbox" name="add_overtime_hours" id="add_overtime_hours"  value="" size="1" maxlength="1" />
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="text">
                <span class="hours">
                    <input onclick="addhours(this, event);" type="button" value="Add Labour" />
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
```

I'm not sure where to even start on this

thank you for your help

Comment: Now that I've indented your code you can see that your HTML has some missing/extra tags

Comment: Thank you Rory the html is a selection from the main form so I must have missed the end part. Thanks

Comment: did you tried $("#add_over_time_hours").prop('checked') ? refer this  for further details.

Comment: Thanks Isensical the checkbox part is working well but that is just for displaying on the current page I want to be able to save a 1 to the database so that when I load the database hours in the the edit screen I can then bring the checkbox status in again to add and edit the hours.

Comment: so if you want to save value 1 into database check if above returns true, if so save 1 into your database.

Comment: Thanks for that I'm just not sure how to go about doing that though. I can do it outside of the array but when I get into the function which creates the array I'm getting stuck. My though was to add a text field and fill this with either a 1 or 0 created from the checkbox which I then know how to put into the database but it just returns 1 everytme. I'm still quite new to web programming so still just learning. thanks